# JWT differences between jose4j and jjwt dependencies in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

can anyone spot the difference between using jose4j from bitbucket or jjwt from jsonwebtoken to provide authentication in my app. I've been requested to implement the security and I have no idea which one to choose.

There's a lot of info about jjwt but bearely any of jose4j.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just different implementations of the same thing. Currently JWT does not support JWE, but JOSE4j does. So I think you can choose according to your needs.